# How to submit a form from an element to a controler and store it in another model

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have a controller Users_controller and a function travel().i have a view travel.ctp for that function.in travel.ctp i use an element profile.ctp  to display some content that is stored in the views/element/profile.ctp.
in the travel.ctp i added the element by

```
  <?php echo $this->element("profile");?>
```

in the profile.ctp elemet i write the form action like below

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => 'travel')));?>
```

my doubt is

1. how i get the form data in the travel() ?
2. how to save that data in another table?
3. how can i reuse that element? because i write one action for that form submisson, then how can i reuse that for another action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you have to set for example a variable

```
$this->set('result', 'something');
```

and in your travel.ctp to pass the value "something" to your element included:

element("profile", array('result' => $result));?>

Into your profile.ctp you can use this variable normally like:

```
$result
```

To save data into another table you can change the name of the form

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => 'travel')));?>
```

or not set the name of the form and manually into your controller load the model where you want to save your data

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => array('action' => 'travel')));?>
```

if you want to reuse the element but changing the action you can pass a value that set the action like:

In your travel.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->element("profile", array('result' => $result, 'action' => 'youraction'));?>
```

In your profile.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => $action)));?>
```

Comment: u there? i have some more doubtsin ur answer?